# Setting Contract's statecode and statuscode

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am creating a new contract with early bound objects and trying to set its state and status to something else than new/draft.

I tried creating the new Contract with the status and state, but state is read only.

I tried creating the new contract, saving changes, and then executing a SetStateRequest on my context. That didn't work and gave me an error saying that "the state is invalid this contract cannot be cancelled" (same if I tried with active status). I get the same error if I try to change the state with all 3 overload of the SetState function

I tried creating the new contract, not saving changes and then changing the state, but I would get errors saying that contract with an empty GuiD couldn't be found. I also tried by giving it a specific Guid, but that didn't work either.

I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328503.aspx) exaplining that in order to set a contrat to cancelled, I have to set it to Invoiced, but when I try to set the contract to invoice I get this message : The billing start date / billing end date is invalid, this contract can not be set to invoice state.

I'm running out of ideas, can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Contract` entity most status changes are controlled by built-in business logic. E.g. you cannot change the `statuscode` part of a contract that is Invoiced or Active. Contract state can only follow a strict predefined flow.

Keep in mind a contract in another state than `Draft` is nearly read-only and you cannot customize this built-in behaviour. If you need to make - even modest - customizations to the contract entity, think twice before using this entity. In most cases you are far better off creating a custom entity.

Also good to mention, there is a `CancelContractRequest` message that is required to cancel contracts.

Comment: First, the contracts i'm trying to modify are new contracts, which means they are set as Draft. When I try to set them to cancel, by any means I described before or with the CancelContractRequest, I get an error stating that "The state is invalid, this contract cannot be cancelled." with no reason as to WHY the contract cannot be cancelled.

Comment: You can get a contract in Draft state only into the Active or Invoiced state. This is built-in, not-customizable behaviour of the contract entity.

Comment: Then, how do I get it to cancelled from draft ?

Comment: You can't. This is one of the reasons why I'm writing in my answer that in most cases you are far better off creating a custom entity in stead of trying to mold the contract entity to fit your needs.